# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.pickers'?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm XDoanh - A newbie in stackoverflow, I have a problem that need your answer:

The current versions of [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) and [kivymd](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/timepicker/) that I am using are the latest versions but when importing one of the classes from them i get an **ERROR** as title although the kivymd documentation says about that class and it seems to work fine... Has anyone encountered this error or has a solution? *HELP ME :(*

> thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't that be `kivymd.uix.picker` instead of `kivymd.uix.pickers`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well when exploring their [kitchen sink demo](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/tree/master/demos/kitchen_sink).
I was able to fix this by editing the file [libs/baseclass/pickers.py](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/libs/baseclass/pickers.py) from `from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker` to `from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker` and it worked after that.